# Nativescript call to certain action after tapping android push-plugin notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, nativescript, phonegap-pushplugin

Im using https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin to receive push notification. When I tap on received notification, it opens main page app. is there a way to receive data and call certain action to open notification message in different view when app is lunched and not main page?

Comment: I know this is old, but i´m looking for this to...do you have the answer? regards

Comment: Im looking for the same, the function to navigate to the view I want does not get executed if the application is in background, so do you have a clue how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You should send action data along with.

for example:

```
{
    data: {
        action: 'user.registered',
        objectId: "1"
    }
}
```

in messageRecieveCallback = check action and trigger action with route navigation.

Comment: Can you give more details about how this actually could be implemented?